# Create Executable file for finished application in C# project

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, installation

It's probably an easy question for you all, but I have never done this so I would not know where to begin.
I have finished my project in visual studio (it's a WPF application) and, I want to make an executable file or setup if need be, as I'm using some DLL's that are not a part of the standard framework library. How do I go about to do that, so I can run my application on other people PC without installing Visual studio on it?

I have tried Publishing and app, this will create a "manifest app" file(don't know really what that is) but when I start an app but it complains that is unable to load SQLite DLL's, therefore, the app does not function.

My application is using database connection string that in app.config something like this

```
   <connectionStrings> 
     <add name="DBSQLite" connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\userName\Desktop\TestDB.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" 
  </connectionStrings>
```

As you see I'm using full directory path to a database file so an application can save the data to the db file. This will be a problem if other user does not have this file or the file is placed in the wrong directory, or for soem reason I can't load the dll Is there a method that I can create Executable/MSI that will also place the db file into the installation directory so the application can function properly?

Really appreciate the answers

Comment: What ORM framework are you using against sqlite?

Comment: Hello thank you for the replay I'm not sure what ORM framework is but I  download them from Nuget Package manager I can see 4 listed there as installed there are System.Data.SQLite, System.Data.SQLite.Core, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, System.Data.SQLite.Linq. If you could point me how to check what I'm using I would really appreciate as am new to all this and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before creating installer, you should copy all files under bin/debug folder to other machines to test. By the way, you should learn basics of [ADO.NET provider for SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Comment: I did what you suggested, check if all DLL's from SQLite were in bin/debug and just put this on another PC run the app.exe and it did work! I should mention that when I put database file into the bin I did not need to specify full directory path to the file in app.config anymore. So the last thing I need is to create an installer for that Bin/debug so it's in one file or I can just use zip as I don't think I will be needing registering the dll's or gacking them on a system level thanks for your help! 
much appreciated.

Comment: copy paste is better than install, in my opinion.